# Чистая архитектура. Ссылки на абстракции

Tags: архитектура

Читая книгу "Чистая архитектура", я обнаружил, что каждый раз, когда мне в классе нужна ссылка на другой класс, я создаю абстракцию под этот класс и уже объявляю поле типа этой абстракции в 1ом классе. По типу:

```
...
IMove _move = new MoveController();
IView _view = new ConsoleOutputView();
...
```

Насколько такая практика релевантна или я не так понял посыл книги и занимаюсь мракобесием?
По любому иногда же надо иметь ссылки на реализацию, но когда это уместно?

Comment: Да, именно так выглядит принцип инверсии зависимости (DIP) в принципах SOLI**D** по последней букве. Модули верхних уровней должны зависеть от абстракций, а не от конкретных реализаций. Но иногда вступает принцип KISS и плодить сущности ради сущностей тоже не имеет смысла. Классы тоже могут соответствовать определению абстракции, если они не содержат детали реализаций и только контракт для внешнего кода (переделать в интерфейс никогда не поздно). Поэтому под Plain Object никто не создает интерфейсы или чего-то еще. Тут уже нужно думать исходя из конкретики приложения и принимать решения.